# How to simulate the Android enter password dialog box with 'show password' option

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have been able to create a layout in xml for an Alert Dialog with header text, an edittext (for the password) and a checkbox for 'show password'. I am able to retrieve the password when the dialog is closed. What I have been unable to do is to respond clicking on the checkbox.

I have tried numerous attempts using '`Builder.setMultiChoiceItems`' but using that approach adds its OWN checkbox in addition to the one I have in my layout. Also,  sticks it under the title ignoring my layout. I don't want it there! The handler responds to clicks on the rogue checkbox, but not my checkbox.

So how can I use the `Builder.setMultiChoiceItems` approach and use the checkbox in my layout? Or if that is not possible, how can I control where `Builder.setMultiChoiceItems` places the checkbox?

Is there another means of responding to clicks on my checkbox without killing the dialog box? (I can read the state of my checkbox when I exit the dialog but that is not what I want!)

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="24dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_network_password"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/network_password"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff25e6"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/do_not_show"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_password" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My code

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_password_notification, null);
    final String[] items = {getString(R.string.show_password)};

    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.password_dialog_title);
    final EditText edit = dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.edit_network_password);
    builder.setView(dialogContent);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                    boolean isSelected)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got something!");
                    if (selectedItemId == R.id.do_not_show)
                    {
                        if(isSelected)
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Check box Show password");
                            // Show the password
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Hide the password
                            Log.i(TAG, "Check box Hide password");
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Done!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                LniHubAssistantActivity.selectedWifi.setPasskey(edit.getText().toString());
                Prefs.saveToSharedPreference(context, Prefs.WIFI_KEY, LniHubAssistantActivity.selectedWifi.getPasskey());
                //Your logic when OK button is clicked
                finish();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
            }
        });
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can attach a listener to the checkbox, like this:

```
    AppCompatCheckBox showPassword = dialogContent.findViewById(R.id.do_not_show);
    showPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                // hide password
                edit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length());
            } else {
                // show password
                edit.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. You should add to your answer that using the 'setMultichoiceItems' is NOT the way to go!